# jQuery prepend() to Elements that contain Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to prepend() a div to each  that contains at least one div. Something similar to this but something that actually works:

```
if ($('.tooltip-item').children('div').size() > 1) {
$('.tooltip-item').prepend('<div class="star">*</div>');
}
```

My html is set up like this

```
<a id="filterItems" class="tooltips" href="#">XBOX
    <span class="tooltip-container">
        <div class="tooltip-item">Controller</div>
        <div class="tooltip-item">Console
            <div class="filter-item">In Stock</div>
            <div class="filter-item">Pre-Order</div>
        </div>
    </span>
</a>
```

In this example I would like to prepend() my to "Console" only but each method I have tried I end up with a div for each item or no item. How can I prepend to the "Console" div which contains divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through each element, otherwise it will take  only the first element,

```
$('.tooltip-item').each(function () {
    if ($(this).children('div').size() > 1) {
        $(this).prepend('<div class="star">*</div>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in this context to accomplish your task,

```
$('.tooltip-item').filter(function(){
  return $(this).children().length;
}).prepend('<div class="star">*</div>');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gEzDN/)

**Note:** Please inspect the required element to ensure the correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.each()`  in jquery

```
$('.tooltip-item').each(function(){
   $(this).prepend('<div class="star">*</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:has` selector like this:

```
$('.tooltip-item:has(*)').prepend('<div class="star">*</div>');
```

or the `.has()` method:

```
$('.tooltip-item').has('*').prepend('<div class="star">*</div>');
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/TQnn9/4/)

Note that using the `.has()` method is better in performance. You can replace the `*` selector to whatever selector you want, such as `div` for check again the existing of `div` only.

### [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

### [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

Comment: Note this will find any element, OP said he wanted to find `div` children.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, I know that. It's easy to change the selector `*` to whatever he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` to check for whatever condition you require on a specific set of elements. Try this:

```
$('.tooltip-item').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('> div').length > 0;
}).prepend('<div class="star">*</div>');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ab9bL/)

Answer (score 0):

Use **[.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)** or [**:has**](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector.

`.children()` has slight lower performance in this case, as your motive is just to find if the `.tooltip-item` has `<div>`

```
$('.tooltip-item:has("div")').prepend('<div class="star">*</div>');
```

Or

```
$('.tooltip-item').has('div').prepend('<div class="star">*</div>');
```

### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sdPR/)

Answer (score 0):

To check for divs that have filter-item class elements as its children,
Use -

```
$('.tooltip-item:has(".filter-item")').prepend('<div class="star">*</div>');
```

OR 
If you want to check for only divs, then use -

```
$('.tooltip-item:has("div")').prepend('<div class="star">*</div>');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6req8/)

Check out the [usage of :has selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/LcwHL/)**</kbd>

You can use `$(".tooltip-item:has('div')")`

Final answer

```
$(".tooltip-item:has('div')").prepend('<div class="star">*</div>');
```